# Disable Jenkins Log File Usage

Tags: jenkins, diskspace

Jenkins has the cool perk of logging almost everything that happens during your build process. Right now everything is logged in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log.

After regular periods, this file grow to more than 400 GB in space.

Is there any way to disable this "feature"?
As the system the system is used company internally, I would'nt mind, disabling logging at all.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins logging is highly configurable, so you can turn off logging for packages that you;re not interested in.  The configuration is done at:

`$JENKINS_URL/log/`

documentation is at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging

Comment: Thank you! One additional remark: You have to disable the logger interfaces or set the base logger to "OFF" in case you do not want to log anything.